# How can I set both a logger's name and level with a single property in log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

In log4j 1.2 it was possible to set a logger's name and level with a single property like this:

```
log4j.logger.com.acme.xyz.foo = DEBUG
```

In log4j2 the following format must be used:

```
logger.<logger-name>.<logger-property>=<property-value>
```

Therefore it takes at least two properties to set a logger's level:

```
logger.foo.name = com.acme.xyz.foo
logger.foo.level = DEBUG
```

I have a lot of properties similar to these two for setting the level of relevant loggers.

I would love to be able to set them with a single property:

```
logger.foo.name,level = com.acme.xyz.foo,DEBUG
```

or maybe like this:

```
logger.foo.name = com.acme.xyz.foo, DEBUG
```

Does something like that exist n log4j2?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't shorten that up. This was discussed a couple of times (e.g. in [LOG4J2-3406](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3406) or [PR #735](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/735)), but never reached a larger consensus. You can contribute to the JIRA issue to give your perspective (cite the JIRA number in the account request).

While Log4j 1.x had a different syntax for the properties of loggers (`log4j.<property>.<logger name>`) and appenders (`log4j.appender.<appender name>.<property>`), the Log4j 2.x configuration for the most part follows a coherent naming convention (`<parent prefix>.<component id>.<property>`). It would be hard to provide another shortcut notation (except the one introduced in [`LOG4J-3341`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3341)) without breaking something.

You can however write your own [`ConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html) to shorten things up.

Since Log4j 2.x configuration is naturally hierarchical, while the properties format is flat, by using this format you must expect some discomfort. By comparison the other configuration formats are much more elegant:

- XML:

  ```xml
  <Loggers>
      <Logger name="org.apache.logging" level="DEBUG">
  </Loggers>
  ```
- YAML:

  ```yaml
  Loggers:
    Logger:
      - name: "org.apache.logging"
        level: "DEBUG"
  ```
- JSON:

  ```json
  "Loggers": {
    "Logger": [
      { "name": "org.apache.logging", "level": "DEBUG" }
    ]
  }
  ```